# Password Page Alert Box

Tags: javascript, html

I need to put a password protect in one my page. But I want it in a way that when the user click on a menu in my navigation, example is "Gallery", I want an alert box, saying "Enter password to view content" I have used the code below, but it still need to have a button and I don't want that.

P.S. And I prefer to use **javascript** and **html** only.

```
function passWord() {
   var testV = 1;
   var pass1 = prompt('Enter password to view content',' ');

   while (testV < 3) {
      if (!pass1) 
         history.go(-1);
      if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "123456789") {
         alert('You Got it Right!');
         window.open('/gallery');
         break;
      }

      testV += 1;
      var pass1 = prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
   }

   if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV == 3){
      history.go(-1);
      return " ";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Passwords in javascript are trivial to circumvent, and in this case, they could find the password by looking at the source.

Having said that, you could trigger your code by using onclick - `<div class="mymenu" onclick="password();">`

EDIT:
Also, `(!pass1)` is invalid syntax, did you mean `(pass==null)`?